# Stop jquery ajax callback from running

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax function that removes a button  on callback.
In php i have something like this

```
//some checking
if(!$ok)
{
   exit();
}
//500 lines of echo
```

jQuery

```
$.post(url, {}, function(data)
{
    b.remove();
});
```

i dont wanna remove `b` if `$ok=false;`

Comment: check `if(data){b.remove}`

Comment: if (!$ok == false ){b.remove();}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

PHP

```
if($ok){
   echo 1;
}else{
  echo 0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$.post(url,{},function(data){
 if(data == 1){
    b.remove();
 }
})
```

Comment: Actually php
its like
`if(!$ok){
    exit()
}
//500 lines of echo
`

Comment: Json encode and send status and your data seperately

Comment: But there are so many lines of `echo` putting all of em in variable and doing `json` stuff is lot work-stress.
Any better method?

Comment: Please explain all these things question.